# Tcl/tk Button - How I can pass a variable on the command option?

Tags: variables, button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a problem passing variables on the command option, for example:

```
package require Tk
wm withdraw .
destroy .button
toplevel .button

# button.0: puts 0
set count 0
button .button.$count -text $count -command {puts $count}
grid .button.$count -column $count -row 0

# button.1: puts 1
incr count
button .button.$count -text $count -command {puts $count}
grid .button.$count -column $count -row 0
```

However button.0 puts 1 instead of 0. It seems when the button.0 is called it takes the value of the variable at that moment which is 1.

I figure it out that I can use a procedure and a global variable to achieve the desire results, but I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this without resorting to a procedure call.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that for anything genuinely complicated, adding in a procedure call actually simplifies things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to substitute the *current* value of the variable when you define the callback, you need to use a different quoting mechanism:

```
button .button.$count -text $count -command [list puts $count]
```

Answer (score 3):

With your code you create 2 buttons that trigger command:

```
puts $count
```

In your example, when you push button a variable $count is equal to "1", so "puts" and displays this value. For proper operation of the need to create 2 buttons. A first button command should be "puts 0". A second button command should bіt "puts 1". We must apply the substitution when creating the button. For example:

```
-command [list puts $count]
-command "puts $count"
```